# Not calling inner function?

Tags: java

I am trying to debug this code after comming to this line

```
try 
{                   
   String categoryWordStr=getMapValueStr(arrSenStatus.getCategoryKwordTargetV());
    ....
    ....
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it will directly jump to catch block.
    In this code it not calling function `getMapValueStr()` it will directly jump to catch block and throw an exception.

where as my function `getMapValueStr` is

```
private static String getMapValueStr(HashMap<String, String> categoryWordMap)
{
...
...
}
```

I am getting an exception as

> 11:17:37,912 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11:17:37,914 ERROR [STDERR] at
>   org.gov.cdac.aai.eilmt.formatrebuilder.AllFormatProcessor.getHindiLexMap(AllForm‌​atProcessor.java:585)
>   –

It is not going to this function. What is the problem??
please help ...
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Post exceptionTrace e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Why not step through it in a debugger?  I wonder how people program in the dark like this?

Comment: You should treat this as general advice, too - whenever you ask a question which involves an exception, you should *always* include the exception details in the question.

Comment: @Kyle 11:17:37,912 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
11:17:37,914 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.gov.cdac.aai.eilmt.formatrebuilder.AllFormatProcessor.getHindiLexMap(AllFormatProcessor.java:585)

Comment: @AmirAfghani: The OP appears to already be stepping through in the debugger - he's surprised that it doesn't get into getMapValueStr while debugging, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user2469963: You should edit that into the question, not just include it as a comment.

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes thank you I am new in this. I will definetly follow your instructions here on wards

Comment: @JonSkeet - I don't believe it.  If he were debugging, he could view the values of the variables on the stack or step into the getCategoryKwordTargetV method.  I doubt he's doing any debugging, but then again, I could be wrong...

Comment: @AmirAfghani: He may not have thought of looking at that value - he may well be new to debugging. But the post does start with "I am trying to debug this code"

Answer (score 6):

This would happen if:

- `arrSenStatus` is null (`NullPointerException`)
- `arrSenStatus.getCategoryKwordTargetV()` itself throws an exception

Don't forget that the argument is fully evaluated before the `getMapValueStr` method can start to execute.

EDIT: Now that we can see that it *is* a `NullPointerException`, that would suggest that `arrSenStatus` is null. So you either need to guard against that possibility if it's a valid state, or fix whatever problem is causing it to be null if it's meant to definitely *not* be null.

Comment: Jon Skeet can answer before OP completes the question.

Comment: @Karna May be add that to [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) !

Answer (score 0):

```
arrSenStatus.getCategoryKwordTargetV()
```

might be throwing null or an error .. As suggested please try to debug or execute that piece of code seperately .

Comment: yes it is giving null value that but in this function parameter public static LinkedHashMap<String, String> getHindiLexMap(LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkHMWordWordWithTag, String strExtension,String strLanguage,String strDomain,tr.SentenceStatusImpl arrSenStatus){

From SentenceStatusImpl class It need to get getCategoryKwordTargetV() function but when i am debbuing it not going to this class ..thats why I unable to fing out the null value

Comment: Just try to handle the null condition in every function. if(param == null) {//Do something}

Comment: what you want to say please tell me little briefly

Comment: I didn't understand your comment . But from a programmer view , please try to handle the null values of parameters wherever required . Can you please tell me the trouble you are facing now ?

Comment: Now it is giving null value  on arrSenStatus.getCategoryKwordTargetV();

It is variable of parameter getHindiLexMap () function I mentioned it above tr.SentenceStatusImpl arrSenStatus
In SentenceStatusImpl it contain function getCategoryKwordTargetV()
but I am trying to debbuging by applying debug point .but it is not going to that class for debug thats why i am unable to find out null value

Comment: ok . So try to debug the function getCategoryKwordTargetV() . ALso inside the function getMapValStr , handle if the input paramter is null through a null check .